# Android table layout image margin

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following table layout which I'm using to display image buttons in a grid.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/button_one" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/button_two" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/button_three" />
</TableRow>
```

As you can see, the first row contains two columns, and the second row contains one column.

I want the images to expand to fit the table cell.  The edges of image button at the bottom however doesn't quite line up with the two image buttons at the top.  It's as if there is extra padding or margin on the bottom cell.

Any ideas how to get these to line up perfectly?

Thanks in advance.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try replacing all `fitCenter` by `fitXY`

Comment: @vasart That didn't fix the problem :(  I think it might be something to do with the layout_weight, as removing that removes the margins, however then the buttons don't fill the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem...

I was originally using nine-patch drawables for the backgrounds because I had curved corners, however I forgot to remove the border from the image when I switch to regular images with sharp corners... doh!  Redoing the images fixed the problem - my xml was fine as is.

/palmface

Answer (score 0):

as vasart mentioned, replacing all `fitCenter` with `fitXY` will do the trick

updated XML:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem. Same result only the inner image is now distorted.

Comment: @TonyLeeper please upload the images that you used in this case

Comment: Yes, see "android:src" in my example xml in addition to the background. I removed the images for the screen shot because they aren't relevant to the problem and are specific to an app I have on the android app store and didn't want to inadvertently use SO as an advertising platform. I just want the buttons to line up correctly.